# Application Insights React plugin

Tags: reactjs, azure-application-insights, applicationinsights-react-js

I've been playing around with React and Azure App Insights.

```
const appInsights = useAppInsightsContext();
```

For Events and Metrics only, there seems to be 2 ways of doing things. Why is this? And why is it only for these 2 things only ie for PageViews or exceptions you can only use the second way (appInsights.trackPageView, appInsights.trackException)

//first way

```
    const trackEventHook = useTrackEvent(
    appInsights,
    "AppInsightsPage Track Event Hook",
    { extraData: "some extra data important to this" },
    false
  );

trackEventHook({ extraData: "function call extra data" });
```

//2nd way

```
appInsights.trackEvent({ name: "AppInsightsPage Custom Event" }, undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

While using Application Insight, we use TrackEvent in our code to count various events. How often users choose a particular feature or maybe how often they make particular choices.

For Example, we want to understand the user behavior on a site and we want to know about specific actions like clicking the **Add to Cart** button.

This can be done by two ways :

### Using trackEvent Method

```js
appInsights.trackEvent({ name: 'EventName', properties: { anyProperty } })
```

We use appInsights object that we are exporting and pass some data to trackEvent, the **name of the event** we are tracking and any **custom properties** we want to include in the event.

### Using React Plugin useTrackEvent Hook

```js
const trackEventName = useTrackEvent(appInsights, "Event Name", condition);
```

The `useTrackEvent` Hook is used to track any custom event that an application may need to track, such as a button click or other API call. It takes four arguments:

1. Application Insights instance (which can be obtained from the  `useAppInsightsContext`  Hook).
2. Name for the event.
3. Event data object that encapsulates the changes that has to be tracked.
4. skipFirstRun (optional) flag to skip calling the  `trackEvent`  call on initialization. Default value is set to  `true`.

**trackExpection** is used to log exception which are related to API, we don't know when they will happen and for **trackPageView**, page view telemetry is sent by default when each screen or page is loaded. So, in **trackExpection** and **trackPageView** we don't have any data object to track any changes. That's why we don't use **useTrackEvent** hook for this two.

For more information please check the following Microsoft Documents:

- [React Plugins for Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-react-plugin).
- [Application Insight API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#trackevent).

Comment: I think you've answered your own question here, not mine

Comment: I described both the methods and summarized the answer in the last paragraph. Still if you are not satisfied can you please elaborate your question so that I can help.

Comment: the question asks why are there 2 different ways of doing things for track event (and track metric)? Why would I use one over the other...I have already read the documentation... quite clearly you wouldn't use useTrackEvent for trackPageView, why is there no useTrackPageView hook?